# Compare Flex 3 and 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, comparison, adobe, flex4

Where can I find a chart or some article to compare Flex 3 and new 4.

Comment: seems like this is something you could research pretty easily on your own with some googling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official [Adobe Flex 4 Open Source site](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Gumbo) is currently the best place to find information about this upcoming version of the framework. It's worth noting, however, that Flex 4 is still in development, and they don't even consider it beta yet. This could change significantly between now and the final release.

---

UPDATE:

Beta 1 released 1 June 2009.